# saving fragment transaction whereever

Tags: android, android-fragments, transactions, savestate

initially I have an activity A in which I'm gonna open one fragment so here how can i save that fragment
So, that when I launch my application after destroying it restores that fragment in that same Activity in same position

For, answering convenience here's my fragment transaction code:

```
    Fragment newFragment = new ece_frag();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fade_in,R.anim.fade_out);
    transaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, newFragment);
    transaction.commit();
```

Comment: Put this in onCreate of the activity. So whenever the activity is created this fragment is added to it.

Comment: actually i wanted to apply this fragment when button is clicked

Comment: Use shared prefrences for that then you can save the index by indexing all the fragments. Then in onCreate check what was the last fragment and load it.

Comment: and can you help me with this code?

Comment: Ok i'll post this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say you have 3 fragments A,B and C.

I give index to each fragment like this say 0->A, 1->B, 2->C. So when i do this, I also save the index like the code below:

```
Fragment newFragment = new A();
FragmentTransaction transaction = 
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fade_in,R.anim.fade_out);
transaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, newFragment);
transaction.commit();
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putInt("last_fragment", 0);//For fragment A saving index 0
editor.commit();
```

And then in onCreate you can use an if case like this:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
//0 here is the default value
int lastFragment = sharedPref.getInt("last_fragment", 0);
```

Then you can do this

```
switch(lastFragment){
  case 0:
  //Load your fragment Here according to the index.
  break;
  case 1:
  //Load your fragment Here according to the index.
  break;
  case 2:
  //Load your fragment Here according to the index.
  break;

}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: in case 0 I have used previous code for fragment transaction which i have asked in question

Comment: Happy coding.!! :)